# I am trying to pass a Variable from a UITabController to a UIViewController but with no luck?

Tags: swift, xcode, parameter-passing

I have a `UITabController` class inside of which I created an instance for a custom `UINavigationBar`, which I am interested in passing its height to another `UIViewController`. Below is the code that I have inside my `UITabController` class:

```
import UIKit

class NewFileButtonPressedTabController: UITabBarController, UINavigationBarDelegate
{
    let firstViewControllerInTabBar = FirstItemInTabBarOpenRolledSections()
    let secondViewControllerInTabBar = SecondItemInTabBarHollowStructuralSections()

    let navigationBar = CustomNavigationBar(navigationBarTitle: "'Blue Book' Catalogue Sections", leftBarButtonTarget: self, leftBarButtonSelector: #selector(buttonPressed(sender:)))

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationBar.delegate = self
        view.addSubview(navigationBar)

        firstViewControllerInTabBar.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "notSelectedStateOpenSections")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        firstViewControllerInTabBar.tabBarItem.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "selectedOpenSections")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        firstViewControllerInTabBar.tabBarItem.tag = 0
        secondViewControllerInTabBar.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "notSelectedHollowSections")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        secondViewControllerInTabBar.tabBarItem.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "selectedHollowSections")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        secondViewControllerInTabBar.tabBarItem.tag = 1
        let tabBarList = [firstViewControllerInTabBar, secondViewControllerInTabBar]

        viewControllers = tabBarList
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        navigationBar.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        navigationBar.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true

        if #available(iOS 11, *) {
            navigationBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        } else {
            navigationBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        }

        override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            setupConstraints()
        }


        func setupConstraints() {
            firstViewControllerInTabBar.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            firstViewControllerInTabBar.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationBar.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
            firstViewControllerInTabBar.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tabBar.topAnchor).isActive = true
            firstViewControllerInTabBar.view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
            firstViewControllerInTabBar.view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        }
    }

    func position(for bar: UIBarPositioning) -> UIBarPosition {
        return UIBarPosition.topAttached
    }

    override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
        if tabBarItem.tag == 0 {
            let sb = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstItemInTabBarOpenRolledSections") as! FirstItemInTabBarOpenRolledSections
            print("tag 0 has been pressed")
            print(navigationBar.frame.size.height)
            sb.tabBarControllerNavigationBarHeight = navigationBar.frame.size.height
        }
    }
}
```

And the below is the code I have inside the `UIViewController`, which is basically the view to be displayed when the first TabBarItem is pressed, which I would like to pass the navigationBar height to:

```
import UIKit

class FirstItemInTabBarOpenRolledSections: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    var tabBarControllerNavigationBarHeight: CGFloat?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let customCollectionView = CustomCollectionView(layoutTopEdgeInset: 20, layoutBottomEdgeInset: 20, layoutLeftEdgeInset: 20, layoutRightEdgeInset: 20, totalWidthOfCollectionView: self.view.frame.width, totalHeightOfCollectionView: self.view.frame.height, minimumLayoutCellsHorizontalSpacing: 20, minimumLayoutCellsVerticalSpacing: 20, numberOfCellsPerRow: 2, numberOfCellsPerColumn: 4, viewThatCustomCollectionViewWillBeAddedTo: self.view, hostViewDelegate: self, hostViewDataSource: self)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 8
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let myCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath)
        myCell.backgroundColor = .blue
        return myCell
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("User tapped on itme \(indexPath.row)")
    }
}
```

However, every time I print the value for the navigation bar height inside the second view I keep getting a nil, which means that the value has not been passed succesfully. Could someone please help me figuring out what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What seems to be happening is that you are instantiating a new copy of your `FirstItemInTabBarOpenRolledSections` using `storyboard?.instantiateViewController`  your `override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem)` function. And then you are setting the property you want of this brand new copy of your View Controller - which has nothing to do with the view controller that is being displayed.

The property you want to modify is the one from the variable `firstViewControllerInTabBar` in your `NewFileButtonPressedTabController` class, since that copy of your view controller is the one being displayed. So your tabBar's didSelect method should look something like this:

```swift
override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {

        if tabBarItem.tag == 0 {

            print("tag 0 has been pressed")

            print(navigationBar.frame.size.height)

            firstViewControllerInTabBar.tabBarControllerNavigationBarHeight = navigationBar.frame.size.height

        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I actually tried this before and I am still getting a nil value for the tabBarControllerNavigationBarHeight variable inside the FirstItemInTabBarOpenRolledSections UIViewController?

Comment: So I adjusted my code given what you mentioned above but not exactly. Basically I am no longer creating another instance of the firstTabBarItem ViewController. Since I agree with you that I already defined it, there is no point in creating another copy. Then I wrote the needed code to pass the navigationBarHeight inside the viewDidLayoutSubViews() function inside the tabBarController. I am getting a value now for the variable inside the FirstItemInTabOpenRolledSections UIViewController when I print it inside the viewDidLayoutSubViews() function, however, the first time the value is printed as

Comment: nil and the second time the actual value gets printed. I am just wondering why the first time the value is reported as nil. Is it because when the first subView get added, which is the UICollectionView the navigationBar does not exist at that point of time. And then when the NavigationBar gets added as a subView, which is the second tme, a value is reported?